# Is there a widget that can display a certain Custom Post Type Terms?

Tags: custom-post-types

I am looking for a widget that a user can choose a Custom POst Type Term from a list.
As an example I have a Custom Post Type called events and it has multiple categories.
I want the user to be able to choose to show only posts from a certain category.

Does anyone know of one or know how I can make this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have build, some time before a widget,
Also you can set the number of posts, the category and the order!

```
<?php
/****** Widget ******/
class Artdev_Category_Posts extends WP_Widget {

    function Artdev_Category_Posts() {
        $widget_ops = array('description' => 'Add Selected Category Posts to the Sidebar' );
        parent::WP_Widget(false, __('&rarr; Category List', 'artdev'),$widget_ops);      
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {  
        extract( $args );
        $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
        $cat_name = esc_attr($instance['cat_name']);
        $posts = esc_attr($instance['posts']);
        $order = esc_attr($instance['order']);

        echo $before_widget; ?>

            <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

            <?php // The Loop
            $wq = new WP_Query();
            $wq->query( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'category_name' => $cat_name, 'posts_per_page' => $posts, 'orderby' => $order )); 
            if( $wq->have_posts() ) :
            ?>
            <ul class="widgetlist">
                <?php while($wq->have_posts()) : $wq->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

            <?//php } ?>

       <?php echo $after_widget;
   }

   function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {                
       return $new_instance;
   }

   function form($instance) {        
        $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
        $cat_name = esc_attr($instance['cat_name']);
        $posts = esc_attr($instance['posts']);
        $order = esc_attr($instance['order']);
        ?>

        <p><!-- Widget Title -->
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:','artdev'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" />
        </p>

        <p><!-- Category Name -->
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cat_name'); ?>"><?php _e('Category Name:','artdev'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cat_name'); ?>" value="<?php echo $cat_name; ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cat_name'); ?>" class="widefat" />
        </p>

        <p><!-- Number Of Posts -->
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posts'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of posts to show:','artdev'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('posts'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posts'); ?>" value="<?php echo $posts; ?>" size="2" />
        </p>

        <p><!-- Order Posts -->
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('order'); ?>"><?php _e('Order of posts:','artdev'); ?></label>
            <select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('order'); ?>">
                <option value="title" <?php if ($order == 'title') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Order Posts by Title</option>
                <option value="ID" <?php if ($order == 'ID') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Order Posts by ID</option>
                <option value="date" <?php if ($order == 'date') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Order Posts by Date</option>
                <option value="rand" <?php if ($order == 'rand') { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Randomize Posts</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <?php
    }
} 
register_widget('Artdev_Category_Posts'); 
?>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code is there any way to allow the user to choose the category from a dropdown?

Comment: Yes @Lee, it's possible, when i have some time i will update the answer, but if you know how to do this, use the get_terms(). Take a look here also: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/terms-of-custom-taxonomy-in-a-dropdown-menu