# Related posts widget

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I need a widget that does displays the following for related posts

- Post Title
- Thumbnail

Preferably it displays related posts *by category*.

---

So far I tried these widgets, which are partly working or don't working (with WP v3.3):

**Partly working:**

- "Related Links by category": works, but no thumbnails
- "Posts by same category widget": works, but no thumbnails
- "Widgets of Posts by Same Categories": works, but no thumbnails

**Not working**:

- "YARPP - Yet another related posts plugin": shows up, but nothing related.
- "ELI's Related Posts Links and Widget": doesn't even show up in the widget list
- "Related Posts widget": doesn't show up in the sidebar

Comment: So what's your question? Couldn't one of the working plugins be modified into displaying a thumbnail to?

Comment: I could write my own also. But I ain't currently got time for that. I was searching for a take and go solution. After looking through about 20 widgets/plugins, I couldn't find a single one, so I asked here. Sadly the "youngest" plugin had it's last update 93 days ago...

Comment: here is a widget http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36448/2048v You have to edit the query to fit your needs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your happy to accept a solution involving one of the plugins you listed under the **"Partly woking:"** heading.

**Widgets of Posts by Same Categories**
http://svn.wp-plugins.org/widgets-of-posts-by-same-categories/trunk/widgets-of-posts-by-same-categories.php

Only need literally 1 or 2 lines of code, depending on how you want to handle the "*post does not have a thumbnail*" scenario.

Around this area of the plugin file..

```
<?php
$postslist = get_posts("category=$cat_ID&numberposts=$numberposts&orderby=$orderby&order=$order&exclude=$exclude_posts");
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
?>
    <li><a href="<?php print get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php  print get_the_title($post->ID); ?>"><?php  print get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

All you need to add there is something along the lines of the example on the `has_post_thumbnail` [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail).

```
if( has_post_thumbnail() )
    the_post_thumbnail();
```

For example..

```
<?php
$postslist = get_posts("category=$cat_ID&numberposts=$numberposts&orderby=$orderby&order=$order&exclude=$exclude_posts");
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
?>
    <li>
<?php
if( has_post_thumbnail() )
    the_post_thumbnail();
?>
    <a href="<?php print get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php  print get_the_title($post->ID); ?>"><?php  print get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Though i guess it depends how exactly you want the implementation to work..

Does that help? :)

Comment: Worth an upvote. Give me your mail addy, and I send you my login data ;). Thanks mate. As I guess this could interest other people too, I'll leave it as open before marking it as solution, so I can upvote other possible answers as well. k?

Comment: What would i want your login data for? You're welcome to wait to accept an answer though, i'm in no hurry to score votes, was only trying to help ya out.. ;)

Comment: To _finish_ your job! :D

Comment: lol, no chance, i know you're more than capable.. :p